# How do I get only ONE link to change dynamically using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry, I'm not sure how to really word my question. Here it goes.

If you go to my page http://www.eveo.org/stack/view.php you will notice on the right hand side there are links that read "restore" and "delete". If it says restore, the value for the "deleted" table in the database is "y".

**The problem:** When I click on a link, all of them change, not just the one. What I need to do is when I click on "delete" or "restore" on any of them, only that row will delete and restore and only will that rows link update, with all the others staying the same. The value in the database has to change from "y" to "n" or vice versa depending on the link.

The code that currently changes my link for all of them is:

```
echo "<td><a href='view.php?'>";

    $y="$row[deleted]";
    $x="$row[id]";

    if ($y == 'n'){
        mysql_query("UPDATE inventory SET deleted = 'y' WHERE id='$row[id]'");
        echo "delete";
    }
    else if ($y == 'y'){
        mysql_query("UPDATE inventory SET deleted = 'n' WHERE id='$row[id]'");
        echo "restore";
    }

echo"</a></td>";
```

I've been trying to solve this for hours, and it's not working.

**Requirements:** It has to use URL rewriting, so I can't do this change thing with javascript or something, personally I would have, but these are my professors requirements.

Source code:

VIEW.PHP

```
<?php { ?>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>MANUFACTURER</th>
                <th>MODEL</th>
                <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                <th>ON HAND</th>
                <th>REORDER</th>
                <th>COST</th>
                <th>PRICE</th>
                <th>SALE</th>
                <th>DISCOUNT</th>
                <th>DELETE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php } ?>
                <?php

                    // while($r = mysql_fetch_array($resultDeleted)) 
                    // {
                        // echo $r[0];
                    // }

                ?>
                <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$row[id]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[name]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[manufac]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[model]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[descrip]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[onhand]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[reorder]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[cost]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[price]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[sale]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[discont]</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='view.php?'>";

                        $y=$row[deleted];
                        $x=$row[id];

                        if ($y == 'n'){
                            mysql_query("UPDATE inventory SET deleted = 'y' WHERE id='$row[id]'");
                            echo "delete";
                        }
                        else if ($y == 'y'){
                            mysql_query("UPDATE inventory SET deleted = 'n' WHERE id='$row[id]'");
                            echo "restore";
                        }

                    echo"</a></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                } ?>
            <?php { ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: You have provided literally no way for anyone to know how your page is functioning.

Comment: Yeah my bad I hit enter on the entire post way too soon so it submitted it without me completing it. I'm still editing the post.

Comment: would you please show us the source that's doing this ?

Comment: Sorry guys, posted the source.

Comment: The links don't even have an `id` in the query string so how would you target the specific record?

Comment: And please strip all that stuff down to only the relevant code.

Comment: you should turn on error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I just did that, it gave me a bunch of errors which I just fixed. Updated source with error reporting on and corrected a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to get a [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable using the code:

```
$y="$row[deleted]";
$x="$row[id]";
```

This is never going to work. First of all you don't need to add double quotes around your variables. Second the correct syntax for getting the `$_GET` variables is:

```
$delete = $_GET['delete'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

As you can see I have given your variable names better descriptive names.

Second, when you are just adding those variables to a query you will have a huge [SQL injection hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in your application:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE inventory SET deleted = 'y' WHERE id='$id'");
```

What if I was a hacker I would add an `id` of: `1' or 1=1`, which would result in the following query:

```
UPDATE inventory SET deleted = 'y' WHERE id='1' OR 1=1
```

And suddenly I set the deleted status of all records in the table. I could even get into others tables using this attack in do whatever I want.

So you should always use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

mysql_query("UPDATE inventory SET deleted = 'y' WHERE id='$id'");
```

So what you will get is the following:

```
$delete = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['delete']);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

mysql_query("UPDATE inventory SET deleted = '$delete' WHERE id='$id'");
```

Another thing is that you don't need to keep opening and closing the PHP tags. Only if you want to add some HTML.

Next:

instead of echoing all that stuff simply use [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-71):

So instead of doing:

```
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$row[id]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[name]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[manufac]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[model]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[descrip]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[onhand]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[reorder]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[cost]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[price]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[sale]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[discont]</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='view.php?'>";
```

You can simply do:

```
echo <<<HTML
<tr>
<td>{$row['id']}</td>
<td>{$row['name']}</td>
etc
FOOBAR;
```

As you can see it need quotes to get an array element.

After that you should build your links:

```
$delete = 'n';
if ($row['deleted'] == 'n') {
    $delete = 'y';
}
echo '<a href="view.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&delete=' . $delete . '">delete</a>';
```

As a general note:

**ALWAYS ENABLE FULL [ERROR REPORTING](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) ON DEV ENVIRONMENT** so you can see what the f*&k is going on / wrong. So place this at the top of your scripts:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want will not work like that. Your code changes your database entries upon each refresh. To illustrate, if you will keep refreshing your page, the links will change from deleted to restored and vice versa indefinitely.

What you need to do is take those two update clausules out of the loop, give each link an id. Something along the lines of

```
if ($y == 'n'){
    echo "<a href='view.php?link_id=$row[id]&case=delete'>delete</a>";
}
else if ($y == 'y'){
    echo "<a href='view.php?link_id=$row[id]&case=restore'>restore</a>";
}
```

Then somewhere above the loop you would to the actual update.

```
if(!empty($_GET['link_id'])) {
    if($_GET['case'] == 'restore') {
        // udpate 
    } else {
        // update 
    }
}
```

The other way would be to use a form for this. Then you would just catch the post request and do the same thing.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // do stuff
}
```

or

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the id to the query, maybe something like this:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    if($row['deleted']=='y'){$status='restore';}else{$status='delete';}

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['id']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['manufac']}</td>";
    ...
    echo "<td><a href='view.php?id={$row['id']}&do=$status'>".ucfirst($status)."</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
?>
```

Then have the script receive a request to alter the values, something like this would go at the top of your script:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['do'])){
    $set=null;
    $id=(int)$_GET['id'];
    if($_GET['do']=='delete'){$set='n';}
    if($_GET['do']=='restore'){$set='y';}

    if($set != null){
        mysql_query("UPDATE inventory SET deleted = '$set' WHERE id='$id'");
    }
}
?>
```